# SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in Chrome's Javascript console. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript

```
Van count=0;
Fon(i=0;i<code.lenght; i++){
i[(code[i]!—'"|{ 
count=count+codeCharcodeAt(i):}
}
console.log!' Key code is:3554',
Math.floor(Math, sin(Math.log(count))*Math M*1000]-3k
```

How to fix it ? I neet it for some school homework and i dont know how to fix it ... and i got some numbers toot 2548, 2910, 3554

Comment: `Van`? `Fon`? `lenght`? `codeCharcodeAt`?

Comment: I would recommend you to go through a JavaScript tutorial, before you ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Only since it is for school and you have to learn. The next time, please more information and some thoughts by yourself:

```
var count=0;
for (var i=0; i < code.length; i++) {
   if(code[i] != "") { 
      count = count + ...
```

The rest is hard to correct, but you have a starting point